# Failed Compilation of Generic reads[A] Function in Jackson

Tags: scala

I wrote the below `read` method that, given a `json`, de-serializes it into an `A`:

```
import scala.reflect._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

 val Mapper = new ObjectMapper
  Mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  def read[A](json: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[A]): A =
      Mapper.readValue(json, ct.runtimeClass)
```

However, it fails to compile with:

```
[error] /home/kmeredith/src/jackson_sandbox/src/main/scala/net/Test.scala:13: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : _$1 where type _$1
[error]  required: A
[error]       Mapper.readValue(json, ct.runtimeClass)
```

If I remove the return type of `A`, I can then write:

```
  class Person(var name: String)
```

But, when I write:

```
  def readPerson: Person = read[Person]("""{"name" : "bob"}""")
```

It fails to compile with:

```
[error] /home/kmeredith/src/jackson_sandbox/src/main/scala/net/Test.scala:21: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Any
[error]  required: net.Test.Dog
[error]   def readDog: Dog = read[Dog]("""{"age" : 42}""")
```

How can I get `read` to compile with a return value of `A`?

Comment: I think the problem is that readValue takes s `Class[T]` while `ClassTag#runtimeClass` returns a `Class[_]`

Comment: Btw, this seems to be the solution https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper.scala#L56

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by @pedrofurla says, the problem is that `ct.runtimeClass` returns `Class[_]`. You can cast it to `Class[A]` using `asInstanceOf[Class[A]]` but I would avoid it.

You can instead change your implementation to:

`def read[A](json: String, clazz: Class[A]): A = Mapper.readValue(json, clazz)`

You can then call is like:

`val dog = read("......", classOf[Dog])`

Alternatively you can use a different json library for Scala that is type safe. A recommended one that is simple to use is Argonaut.

Comment: Actually, I can't change my implementation to your `clazz: Class[A]` second argument since the `A` is passed as a generic.